# How can I create an Upstart Zip package using sbt-native-packager?

Tags: scala, sbt, upstart, sbt-native-packager

I am unable to generate an upstart zip package.
I have added the following to my sbt project

```
...
enablePlugins(UpstartPlugin).
enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)
```

and then run

```
sbt clean universal:packageBin
```

And a Zip file is produced but it contains the shell script in `./bin` and the jars in `./lib` that look like what is produced when I use `JavaAppPackaging`!

Where are the conf files etc needed for `upstart`? 
Am I missing the secret sauce or using the wrong incantation?

Reading all the docs at [this page](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/introduction.html) I am under the impression that the archetype plugins determine what goes into my package while the format plugins determine what form the package takes.

So for example I could have a Java Server project that is designed to launch running as a daemon user using the `JavaServerAppPackaging` (archetype) and adding the `daemonUser` setting, but then have this bundled up as a Zip or Tar.gz using the Universal (format) plugin or a .deb file using the Debian (format) plugin.

Well I want a Java Service with all the files necessary to be started with the `upstart` System Loader but packaged as a Zip file. So I assume I need the [upstart](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/systemloaders.html#upstart) (archetype system loader) plugin with the [universal](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html) (format) plugin.

There is even a tip on the system loader docs for the upstart plugin saying

> You can use systemloaders with the Java Application Archetype or the Java Server Application Archetype!

Well that exactly what I want ***however it doesn't state how to do it!***

Please can someone tell me how to get a zip bundle with an upstart layout that starts a Java Server application? And if you can point out the documentation I have clearly missed than that would help my understanding too :-)

Cheers

Karl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for ready the docs so carefully and sorry that the docs are lacking an explanation what package types support system loaders.

The short answer is: only `rpm` and `debian` packages support system loaders ( systemd, systemV and upstart ).

Why is that so? A system loader is tight to the target operation system. It's nothing *universal*, which is the reason it's not in there. The configuration files and or scripts and platform dependent and this is not part of your regular application directory.

Cheers,
Muki

Comment: Thanks Muki, i did mis that in the docs... I guess the brain sees what it wants to see.

Comment: However, Upstart does define where it expects to find certain files ( http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/init.5.html#files ) so it is possible to prepare a stage dir that can be zipped or tar.gz'd. The separation between archetype and format plugins could still be maintained? Am I wrong? But it would be nice to have the flexibility, and if I try to run an upstart zip in an OS that does not know what to do with it then that would be my fault, same as trying to run an .deb in an OS that doesn't support apt . But thanks again for answering my question and showing me what I misread.

Comment: ps where does it "clearly states what package types support system loaders"? I looked again but missed it again?

Comment: I really wrote a terrible answer. Auto correct on mobile 

Comment: I meant I'm sorry that the is currently no section describing this. Very misleading what I wrote 

Comment: No worries, would it help if I submitted a pull request to the docs then?